# Cocoa application menubar IBOutlet action to NSViewController - Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, menubar, nsviewcontroller

I have managed to link MyNSViewController NSButton action outlet with the application menu bar menuitem. Here are the step i followed

Changed the existing button action argument type from NSButton to AnyObject

Add an NSObject by side of FirstResponder on ApplicationScene

Changed the class name of added object to MyNSViewController on identity inspector

On popup menu by right clicking on added object Ctrl+drag the IBoutlet action to menu item to link them

This worked well. I am getting the control on action when i click menuitem and succeeded NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(checkURL). But the application brakes when any UI object needs updations. I tried dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ but neither helped.

MyNSViewController is loaded to a placeholder view in ViewController which is by default linked with WindowController the application entry.

I googled but there are much less on google. Every body is explaining to link with AppDelegate. But by getting event there how i call my method which is in MyNSViewController. I am getting the event on MyNSViewController.  Please brief me what i am missing or share some tutorial.

Comment: Connect the menu item action to the First Responder. The view controller is in the responder chain and will get the message.

Comment: I am already getting the message on ViewController and also able to execute method in it. But when come to manipulate UI controls like NSButton set image from bundle it crashed saying exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Comment: Your ViewController is not tied directly to the application delegate. You can have multiple windows and multiple view controllers, so they can't all be responding to the menu item actions.
You need to connect the menu to the appDelegate instead, and have the app delegate pass on the relevant messages to current Window, and that to the view controller. I hope this helps.